# iterate through a multi dimensional hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, loops

I previously posted a question and I was not clear about my intentions. So here I'll try again.

The problem I'm having is that I need to extract the value of amazon and chef separately. Right now they are both held in the b value in my iteration. I tried to create another loop within the value.each but i'm getting an error. How do I efficiently extract both value separately and efficiently?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting my hash from a yaml file this way

```
require 'yaml'
path = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'stage-aws-opscode.yml')
SAO = YAML.load_file(path)
```

The stage-aws-opscode.yml contains the following data

```
sandbox: &defaults
  amazon: aws-green
  chef: mdsol

validation:
  <<: *defaults

cruise:
  <<: *defaults

hendricks:
  <<: *defaults

distro:
  <<: *defaults

performance:
  <<: *defaults

innovate:
  amazon: aws-red
  chef: mdsol-production

production:
  amazon: aws-red
  chef: mdsol-production
```

this is my iteration.

```
<%
 SAO.each do |key, value| 
 parent = "#{key}" 
  value.each do |a, b| 
   "#{a}"  "#{b}"
  end 
end
    %>
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question is still a little unclear. Could you post an example of the expected output? (doesn't need to be HTML, text is fine)

Comment: I think you're asking for a list of amazon followed by a list of chef?

Comment: These values are generated by the yaml file I'm listing above. not sure if this is clear enough but I'll try. The idea is that if a user selects sandbox from a pulldown the value of amazon should be aws-green and the value of chef should be mdsol.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting this:

```
SAO.each do |k,v|
 puts "env: #{k}; amazon: #{v[:amazon]}; chef: #{v[:chef]}; "
end
```

If you're after 2 lists then you need 2 independent loops.

Comment: It's almost what I mean. I will give you an example. The value of amazon should be aws-green and the value of chef should be mdsol if the environment is sandbox. If you look at the yaml example above you'll se what I mean. Thanks

Comment: are you just trying to build a config the same way we do database.yml?
if so you just want `YAML.load_file(path)[RAILS_ENV]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That was not the problem. I have the yaml file working already. It's the iteration through that file and it's content that I'm having problems with.

Comment: You still haven't properly explain what you wanted the output to look like.

Comment: SAO.each do |k,v|
 puts "env: #{k}; <-- this is the sandbox value   amazon: #{v[:amazon]} <-- this would be the aws-green value ;  chef: #{v[:chef]} <-- this would be the mdsol value; "
end